# Distributed batch processing with Spring Batch and AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-batch, amqp, spring-amqp

I want to distribute the processing of large batches. The idea is to use Spring Batch fire up a bunch of AMQP consumers in a cloud and then to load cheap tasks (like item IDs) and submit them to an AMQP exchange. Writing of the results will be done by the consumers themselves.

Is there a ready-made library to accomplish this?

A few thoughts:

- Spring Batch is totally negotiable.
- Batch size is several millions. I don't want to kill my message broker by brute-force submitting all these IDs at once but use some kind of throttling instead.
- I do want to know about what items have been processed so I can monitor the process. So the batch controlling process will have to receive replies from the consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see the [spring-batch-integration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-integration) project. It combines Spring Batch and Spring Integration to perform what you want.

For batch 2.2.x, it's part of the `spring-batch-admin` distribution; in the upcoming batch 3.0.0 release it's been moved to batch proper.

Remote partitioning just sends metadata about the partitions and the workers actually fetch the data.

It comes with a [JMS example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-integration/src/test/resources/org/springframework/batch/integration/partition/JmsIntegrationTests-context.xml) but it wouldn't be hard to swap out the spring-integration JMS gateways for spring integration amqp gateways.

There's also a remote chunking version where the data is sent over the transport instead of partition metadata.

Comment: I am trying to do simiar thing, can you please guide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110211/can-we-use-amqpitemreader-and-amqpitermwriter-for-request-reply-use-case-in-spri ?